# Linear Regression argument "x" is missing with no default

Tags: r

im brand new to coding in R and im having issues with my lm function.

```
f <- lm(comm_YLL ~ region, data = hw1) # this saves properly
plot(xlab = 'years of life lost', ylab = 'reagression') # this returns the error below

abline(f) # haven't gotten this far
```

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>         argument "x" is missing, with no default

I have no idea what any of this means, and am just generally confused how the lm function works. in this case comm_yll is a years of life lost to whatever, and region is what region a country is in. hw1 is the data im dragging this from

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? (see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I believe the reproducible example would be http://prntscr.com/r7q7xy with a regression line showing positive or negative slope y=a+bx, im still new to stack overflow so i am sorry ahead of time if this isnt what you wanted @dc37

Comment: That's a picture of a scatterplot, not a set of data we could run your code on. You should read through the link @dc37 posted. You called `plot` without anything to plot, just labels but no data

Comment: I think a reproducable, is this 

`f <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

plot(mtcars$disp, mtcars$mpg)

abline(f)`

I was trying to mimick this code with my own data and it created the screenshot up above

Comment: Do you still have an error though? Because this plot code has data, whereas the original did not. You can [edit] the post to include additional information

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have mentioned above without a reproducible example it is hard to understand the true problem here.
At a guess, your plot function does not call any data.
You need to specify a vector for the 'x' variable in the function.
Try

```
plot(x = hw1$comm_YLL, y = hw1$region, xlab = 'years of life lost', ylab = 'reagression')
```

Also, note that your `lm` associates the response variable `comm_YLL` as a y axis variable on a plot and the predictor `region` as an x axis variable. So perhaps you want.

```
plot(x = hw1$region, y = hw1$comm_YLL, xlab = 'reagression', ylab = 'years of life lost')
abline(f)
```

Or

```
plot(region ~ comm_YLL, ,data = hw1, xlab = 'reagression', ylab = 'years of life lost')
abline(f)
```

Comment: I don't think your code can work. Take the built-in dataset for example, try `plot(x = mpg, y = disp, data = mtcars)`.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenTsai you are right, I should have checked my work. I usually use the tilda to define my plots. edited

Answer (score 0):

Data from your comment:

```
hw1 <- data.frame(comm_YLL = c(17, 50, 84, 21, 12, 18),
                  region = c(5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2))
```

Assume that

- Predictor variable(X) : *region*
- Response variable(Y) : *comm_YLL*

**Simple Linear Model**

```
mod <- lm(comm_YLL ~ region, data = hw1)
```

---

**Plot**

Actually `plot` is a generic function that it calls other functions according to what you input. There are 2 ways to plot X, Y, and regression line.

**1. Input a `formula` object**

In this way, `plot` call `plot.formula` to do the plotting job and you need to set `data = hw1` to tell this function `region` and `comm_YLL` come from `hw1`.

```
plot(comm_YLL ~ region, data = hw1)
abline(mod, col = 2)
```

**2. Input 2 vectors separately**

`plot` call `plot.default` and you need to use `$` symbol extracting values in `hw1`.

```
plot(hw1$region, hw1$comm_YLL)
abline(mod, col = 2)
```

[image]

If you just want the regression line, set `type = "n"` in `plot`.

```
plot(comm_YLL ~ region, hw1, type = "n")
abline(mod, col = 2)
```

[image]